# SharePoint 2003 Issues List with 6500 items For migration to SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, migration, sharepoint-2003

I have a SharePoint 2003 issues list that is in a sub site and it is set to be migrated to SharePoint 2010. We have tried to use DocAve to migrate this issues list but it is not taking the whole list over, items are being missed out and the history for thhe items in the list are being copied, delete or not going over in the migrate.

The issues list in 2003 is designed very poorly with 100's of check boxes and has over 6500 items so on the one time it was migrated successfully we hit the SharePoint 2010 throtteling issue so the temporary solution was to revert back to 2003. However, in the past few weeks the 2003 servers are being turned off at the end of the month. So the SharePoint team I belong to is on a tight schedual.

What we have tried.

- All the DocAve migrates and none of them seem to work to get all the
  items in the list over.
- Have tried to use front page but it misses out the subsite.
- Cannot export to excel as it does not keep the comments on the items
  in the issue list.

Are there any ways that this can be done that you may know about?

Answer (score 0):

*The issues list in 2003 is designed very poorly with 100's of check boxes and has over 6500 items so on the one time it was migrated successfully we hit the SharePoint 2010 throtteling issue so the temporary solution was to revert back to 2003.*

Is it an option to increase the query throttling limit in Central Admin? You could do this to migrate the list. After that, you should index the columns you query against, and finally revert the query throttling limit to 5k.

Comment: Have tried to do that but now DocAve won't migrate the whole list with all the items. Misses around 1000 items out and some of the comment history off.

Comment: Are you letting DocAve create the list fields for you? I've found that DocAve doesn't migrate some of my list content properly unless I create the list fields in the target environment before migration.

I suggest recreating an empty list in Sharepoint 2010, create the problematic fields on this new list, and then try to migrate again. DocAve support is pretty good, especially if the tool is not working as expected; you should definitely get in touch with them if you haven't already notified them of the migration errors (list items not migrated, missing comments).